# How to break words and numbers using tokenization

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to configure custom tokenization rules for a field that will break words containing letters and numbers into separate tokens? For example, I'd like the string "50pc" to be split into two tokens "50" and "pc".

I could create an override for each number character to treat it as a symbol, but that would give me three words "5", "0" and "pc", which is not what I want.

Is it even possible to do this using tokenization, or do I need to pre-process the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tokenizer overrides](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-tokenization) are designed to split forms like `10x4` into `10` and `4`. Splitting without a boundary character looks impossible at first. But... you can make a tokenizer override field-specific. So here's an (untested) idea.

- Create a field that uses [`admin:database-add-field-tokenizer-override`](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-add-field-tokenizer-override) to classify numeric characters as `remove` or `punctuation`. Configure the field root, includes, and excludes as desired.
- Create another field that does the same for alphabet characters.
- Leave the ordinary word-query field alone.

With that configuration you should still be able to use `cts:word-query` to match `50pc`, as well as using a `cts:field-word-query` to match either `50` or `pc`.

However preprocessing might still be the best way to handle `50pc`. That way you could include the units in the markup, as `<pieces xmlns="http://example.com/2014/units" value="50">50pc</pieces>` — or something along those lines. That may give you more flexibility in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, customized tokenization doesn't give you that amount of flexibility right now.

Consider whether it is actually a problem for there to be three tokens "5", "0", "pc". It depends on your application, your data, and the kinds of queries you're doing. It will make a difference for wildcarding, and for longer numbers you may get more complex queries or require positions to get them to resolve accurately unfiltered because for the field queries, the numbers turn into phrases. You will get longer term lists than you would otherwise, and in some cases this may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but is this the answer:

```
tokenizer.wordChars('_', '_');
```

please clear more if it isn't.